# Chrome Extension: Dynamically add urls to the popup page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am able to get the URL. I want to add the URL to my popup.html. However, the popup.html page only displays one URL (the last one).

**popup.html**

```
<head>
<script src="time.js"></script>
</head>
<body">
<div id="newDiv"></div>
</body>
```

**time.js**

```
loadPara();
function loadPara()
{
   element = document.getElementById("newDiv");
   para = document.createElement("p");
   node = document.createTextNode("New URL");
   para.appendChild(node);
   element.appendChild(para);
} // I have only added enough code to put some light on my problem
```

The above method only adds one `<p>` to the `<div>` dynamically. However I want to add multiple `<p>`(every time the `browserAction` icon is clicked).

I have seen a few similar posts but none of them worked. I have been on it for quite sometime and cant seem to figure it out.(This is the last step that needs to be done before I complete my extension)

I'm new to chrome extension development and any help will be appreciated. If there is anything more I can add to improve clarity, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The `popup.html` is not a stateful page. It is reloaded every time you open the popup hence `loadPara` is only ever run once.

I do not know why you would expect otherwise, to be frank. It is never the case that javascript in a `script` tag runs again with DOM changes persisting.

What this typically requires is an event model, i. e. something like `onPopupOpen`.

If you want persistence, save your information in `localStorage`, `chrome.storage` or a myriad of other persistence engines available.